# update database table with button

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to update my databse with a button to set the visibility from 0 to 1. There isn't any syntax error but for some reason it doesn't change the database value. My database example: (visibility is tinyint with default 0 value)

```
 id-   name-   visibility
---------------------------
1   -   John    -    1
---------------------------
2   -   Ben     -    1
---------------------------
3   -   Terry   -    0
---------------------------
```

and my php code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, name, image, description, address, phone, phone2, email, job, visibility FROM cards";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));          
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
<div class="col-md-4" <?php if ($record['visibility'] == 1) echo " style='display: none';"; ?>>I want this to be hidden here</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="update">Accept</button>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$allowed = mysqli_query($conn," UPDATE cards SET visibility = '1' WHERE id = '$id' ");
}
?>
//html stuff here
 <?php }
      ?>
```

Comment: When you say " it doesn't do anything" you mean that the page doesn't change or the database value is not updated?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The database value doesn't change.

Comment: I think you don't replace `$id` with an existing id

Comment: Where exactly is `$id` set in that code?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to wrap your button into a `<form>` and set its `type to submit`. Furthermore you need to pass the `records id` with it. Try this example:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, name, image, description, address, phone, phone2, email, job, visibility FROM cards";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));          
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) { ?>

  <div class="col-md-4" <?php if ($record['visibility'] == 1) echo " style='display: none';"; ?>>

    Record name: <?php echo $record['name']; ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input value="<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" name="id">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="update">Set visibile</button>
    </form>

  </div>

<?php } ?> 

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $allowed = mysqli_query($conn," UPDATE cards SET visibility = '1' WHERE id = '$id' ");
}
?>
```

If you get this to work, you should search about `prepared statements`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working on his own way but the input field is not a good solution for me. How can I get the id of it automatically?

Comment: You can set it to `display: none`. Perhaps you can work with `AJAX` then you dont need a form and can work with `data-attributes`.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)